# how to pass 1000 random numbers 1-10 only, to scanf such that I can output how many of each occurance is seen?

Tags: c

My goal is to produce a program which can take a random number from the user (srand) and then feed it to a random number generator (rand) which then chooses 1000 iterations of a random number between 1 and 10.  I then want to output how many of each number was seen (i.e. 7 appears 83 times, etc).

I'm able to printf 1000 numbers between 1 and 10 randomly after taking the initial digit from the user, but can't figure out how to take this output and feed it to an array which can then be used to break down the information for printing.  Can anyone please help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int rand1(void);
void srand1(unsigned int seed);

int main()

{
    int rand_array[1000];
    int count;
    int start=1;
    int end=10;
    int number_var;
    int ones=0;
    int twos=0;
    int threes=0;
    int fours=0;
    int fives=0;
    int sixes=0;
    int sevens=0;
    int eights=0;
    int nines=0;
    int tens=0;
    int frequency[11];
    int i=0;


    unsigned seed;



    printf("Please enter your choice for seed.\n");
    printf("(between 1-10)");

    while (scanf("%u", &seed) == 1)

    {
        srand1(seed);



        for(i=0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            rand_array[i]=rand1()%(end-start+1)+start;
            frequency[rand_array[i]]++;
        }

        for(i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {
            printf("There are %d %d's\n", frequency[i], i);
        }


    }


    return 0;

}





int rand1(void)

{
    static unsigned long int next = 1;

    next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return (unsigned int) (next/65536) % 32768;
}




void srand1(unsigned int seed)

{
    static unsigned long int next = 1;
    next = seed;
}
```

Comment: The statement `*rand_array=rand1()%(end-start+1)+start;` only assigns the random number for the first value of the `rand_array`. You should use `rand_array[count]`. Also, the second call to `scanf` (or the outcommented `printf`) is _not_ part of the for-loop.

Comment: and the first scanf is in a while loop for some reason

Comment: I'd agree, but *rand_array=rand1()%(end-start+1)+start; does allow the following print statement to output 1000 numbers.  When compiled and run, 1000 random numbers between 1 and 10 print out on the screen.  I just don't know how to harness the output so it can be sorted and/or analysed....

Comment: But @JoachimPileborg just told you how you could do it. However, you don't actually *have* to store the random numbers to analyze them - you can analyze them on the spot, too!

Comment: I've edited the code(above), and it's further, but now reporting crazy numbers for each number's occurance (eg. 21849595 times 7 appeared).  Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have an array of size 10 (or 11), type integer, where each slot represents the number of times that number is generated.  For example, slot 3 would represent the number of times you generated a 3.  So try this:

```
//declare array to hold frequencies
int frequency[11];

//reset all slots to 0
for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
{
  frequency[i] = 0;
}

//for each random number, increment the associated slot in the frequency array
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
  frequency[rand_array[i]]++;
}

//print the results
for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
{
  printf("There are %d %d's\n", frequency[i], i);
}
```

Note: I did not really read through most of your existing code, so I'm not sure if you have any other issues.

Edit: Here is an example of the general idea.

Say you have some random numbers:

```
5, 2, 4, 9, 9, 2, 1, 10
```

Your `frequency` array starts at 0s:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

So now we loop over your random numbers, and increment the associated slot.

For example, we read the 5, now our frequency array is:

```
[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Then the 2:

```
[0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Then the 4:

```
[0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Then the 9:

```
[0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0]
```

Again

```
[0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,2,0]
```

At the end:

```
[1,2,0,1,1,0,0,0,2,1]
```

Now we know how many of each number there are! Say we want to know how many 9's there were, we just look at the 9th slot and we see that there were 2 of them.

Does this make more sense? This is much better than having 10 separate variables for each number, and then saying "if the number was a 1, increment my 1s variable, if it was a 2, increment the 2s variable".  Plus if you have, say, random numbers between 1 and 100 instead of 1-10, it will be much easier to adapt your code.

Comment: So you mean, have ten arrays, one for each of the possible numbers and replicate the above for each of them?

Comment: I doubt you need ten arrays if you aren't planning in storing the results but only need to print them out. You can reuse the `frequency` array in subsequent runs.

Comment: I've added the code as suggested, but I'm not sure exactly what it does and equally importantly, why it now crashes after compiling and ran...

Comment: I've edited the code(above), and it's further, but now reporting crazy numbers for each number's occurance (eg. 21849595 times 7 appeared). Help?

Comment: See my edit, hopefully this will help you understand the theory behind it.

Comment: You need to initialize the frequency array to 0.  Before you initialize it, the contents of the array is garbage (usually big, meaningless numbers, but can be anything).  So when you go to populate it, you are only incrementing the garbage numbers, making them still meaningless.  Loop through the frequency array once and set all the slots to 0, or use memset or something equivalent.  I edited my code above to show you how to do this.

Comment: Ahhh, now it does make sense yes!  Thank you for taking the time to explain.  The array was uninitialized.  Code is edited and working as expected now.